# Erase the page from an ajax jquery request to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have an ajax post request for a form submit where i manipulate the page based on the values that are returned from the controller but my problem is that whenever the form is submitted i need to erase the values from the last request.For example, i submit the form and when that happens i add some text on the page if the form is submitted a second time i need to erase those values from the last time and add on the page new content.

Here is the code:

```
 function ajaxPost(){

        // DO POST
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "/search",
            dataType: "json",
            data : {
                  'marcaId': $('#marcaId').val(),
                  'modelId': $('#modelId').val(),
                  'pretDeLa': $('#pretDeLa').val(),
                  'pretPanaLa': $('#pretPanaLa').val(),
                  'anFabrDeLa' : $('#anFabrDeLa').val(),
                  'anFabrPanaLa' : $('#anFabrPanaLa').val(),
                  'orasParam' : $('#orasParam').val()
            },
            success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);

                for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                    $('.row.autovitElements').append("<div class='col-sm-3 elementAutovit'>" + "<div class='card' style='width:20rem;'>" +
                            "<img class='card-img-top' src=" + JSON.stringify(data[i].img) + "alt='Card image cap'>" +
                            "<div class='card-body text-center'>" +
                                "<p class='card-text text-center' style='color: black'>" +data[i].title+ "</p>" +
                                "<ul class='list-group list-group-flush'>" + 
                                    "<li class='list-group-item'>" + 
                                        "<div class='row'>" +
                                            "<div class='col-md-6'>" +
                                                "<i class='material-icons'>&#xe227;</i><span>"+ data[i].price +"</span>" + 
                                            "</div>" +
                                            "<div class='col-md-6'>" + 
                                                "<i class='material-icons'>&#xe0c8;</i><span>"+data[i].city+"</span>" +
                                            "</div>" + 
                                        "</div>" +
                                    "</li>" +
                                "</ul>" +
                                "<button href=''#' class='btn btn-danger'>Save</button>" +
                            "</div>" +
                        "</div> " +
                    "</div> ");

                }

        })
```

I've tried with `$('.row.autovitElements').hide();` but it won't work:(

Comment: Try `$('.row.autovitElements .elementAutovit').remove()`  You are appending `elementAutovit`, so those would be the elements you remove

Comment: It looks like it works that way, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  $('.row.autovitElements').append("<div class='col-sm-3 elementAutovit'>" + ...
```

The elements you are appending for the results of the ajax are `elementAutovit`, which are children of the `.row.autovitElements` element.  So to "reset" the results, you would remove all those elements you appended, which could be done with:

```
$('.row.autovitElements .elementAutovit').remove()
```

Which would remove all those specific elements.  OR, if there is nothing else in the container that you want to keep, you could simply empty it

```
$('.row.autovitElements').empty()
```